# How do I add ASP.NET server controls to my MVC4 views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

As the account name claims, I am indeed a n00b.  ;)

I'm new to MVC. I'm just trying to add an `<asp:Label/>` to one of the default views that were stubbed in when the project was created. But nothing shows up in intellisense and there's no `@Register` anywhere in the solution with a tagprefix of "asp". I get a warning on build, ***"Unrecognized namespace 'asp'"***, then the label doesn't show up on the page when I run the site.

I guess I've always just took for granted that in other non MVC web projects there was a tagprefix="asp" listed somewhere. But after scouring the internet for an answer, I've not been able to turn anything up on how to do this in MVC. Seems like it should be something turnkey vs. me having to struggle to find an answer.

How do I get MVC4 to recognize ASP.NET controls? How would I be able to do templates or grids or anything without this reference being stubbed in?

Comment: MVC doesn't recognize Web Forms Controls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Don't do that.

The whole point of ASP.Net MVC is that it doesn't use server controls.

Instead, you should write raw HTML and use HTML helpers (the `@Html.*()` methods)

Comment: If I can upvote your answer a million times I would, just to tell people that please, don't **ever** do that.

Comment: LOL...ah. Ok. I consider myself educated. Does that mean I have to build things like grids using old-timey tables or be fancy with div's? What about things like column header sorting on a grid?

Comment: @IAmAN00B: There are various third-party helpers that do fancy grids.

Comment: Check out WebGrid for an easy way to do grids in MVC - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: There are loads of third party controls to use with MVC e.g. Telerik Kendo MVC wrappers.  JQuery offer a lot of free client side controls (see http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Awesome! Looks like that WebGrid is just what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The MVC framework is not designed for server side controls. In fact, you do not have server side controls at all in mvc. All you have to do is to use standard html controls.

I think you should read a bit more on MVC before diving in. This is an entirely different approach compared to web forms and trying to compare things will cause too much confusion and hardship. You might have to unlearn what you have learned with hard efforts.

Comment: I've been reading as much as is free. Did the tutorials at the Microsoft site. But there's no definitive statement of what you're saying anywhere. It's a bit misleading. And I'm still a bit in the dark on how to do things the server controls did. The whole point of server controls is to minimize hand-coded development and not having to reinvent the wheel every time I want a sortable grid or something.

Comment: You can still reuse the code with Html helpers in MVC. In fact there are lots of such available. Look for http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid. Whole point here is abstraction of design from code and absolute control over html rendering which was not possible with server side controls as they emitted their own html.

Comment: You can use Partial Views too which are similar to controls in which you can use them to render common markup which you can reuse. No code behind element to them though.

Comment: Free is the name of the game. I guess I take issue with having to pay for something as simple as a grid. Also, a good portion of RAD goes out the window with me having to purchase a 3rd-party control with the learning curve that obviously will come with implantation of the control. I'd rather just build my own, even if it isn't doesn't look as nice or behave the same.

Comment: Here is one which is free http://flexigrid.info/ - a little effort and you will find a lot of others too

Answer (score 0):

Because MVC does not maintain state information by using view state.
So we can't use Asp.Net server side control which are capable of doing postback.
The Execution life cycle of a .aspx page and ASP.NET MVC application is different, MVC dosen't support many of the .aspx page life cycle events, because the interactions between the model, view, and controller use a different life-cycle model.